# too many indices for array when calculating the cost (loss) for softmax function

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, ipython

when runnig following code:

```
log_likelihood = -np.log(AL[range(m),(Y.T)])
cost = np.sum(log_likelihood) / m
```

I'm running into following error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

What I'm try to do is calculating the Cost (loss) when using the softmax activation function in the last layer. But I'm doubt about the correctness of the use of the loss function. Can somebody help me out. Below the values for Y, AL and m. 
Also take a note of my question on bottom below.

```
m = 103

AL = 

    [ 0.00053812  0.00056333  0.00044308  0.00049186  0.00052197  0.0004967
      0.00053772  0.00050893  0.00056395  0.00048245  0.00054108  0.00049916
      0.00051731  0.00052541  0.00053263  0.00048361  0.00053443  0.00048592
      0.0005369   0.00048774  0.00046664  0.0005595   0.00050006  0.00049927
      0.00058505  0.00050388  0.00050758  0.00048509  0.00045316  0.00051437
      0.00051699  0.0005191   0.00056063  0.00049081  0.00045165  0.00052115
      0.00047442  0.00050923  0.00055636  0.00051289  0.00052355  0.00048346
      0.00055642  0.00052013  0.00054893  0.00050218  0.00053943  0.00054195
      0.00053007  0.00050605  0.00050269  0.00054989  0.00055924  0.00051879
      0.00052424  0.00048354  0.00054938  0.00049948  0.00051457  0.00049498
      0.00051916  0.00050104  0.00049024  0.00052853  0.00056007  0.00049898
      0.00053602  0.00049939  0.00049951  0.00050225  0.00054669  0.00048918
      0.00054973  0.00050006  0.00053826  0.00050138  0.00050121  0.0004877
      0.00051502  0.00049806  0.00051322  0.00050482  0.00051072  0.00057624
      0.00050472  0.00048504  0.00055405  0.00047917  0.00057005  0.0004953
      0.00053256  0.00049632  0.0004982   0.0005257   0.0004773   0.00051911
      0.00051558  0.00049666  0.00053804  0.00053818  0.00054405  0.000544
      0.00054372]

Y transform (Y.T) =

    [[1]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]
     [0]]
```

Also I'm wondering if it is correct to use the one-hot encoded vector for Y, or should I use the real label vector?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `AL` is a one-dimensional array and you're trying to access it as if it was a 2D array.

A 2D array looks like this:

```
[[1, 2],
 [3, 4],
 [5, 6]]
```

You can see this in `Y.T`, which is actually two-dimensional.

In the first line you wrote `AL[range(m),(Y.T)]` which tries to access `AL` using two indices, which is wrong.

You should either make `AL` to be truly 2D or use a single, one-dimensional index.

Comment: OK tnx, and what about: Also I'm wondering if it is correct to use the one-hot encoded vector for Y, or should I use the real label vector?

Comment: @Ilse This new question is completely different from your starting question. You have to ask a new question.

Comment: Considering SO's usage, it's better to post unrelated questions separately. A person who has the same question will have a greater chance of finding your question and benefiting from the answers you receive.